# How to check if products added to cart have free deliveries conflict with each other

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, shopping-cart, laravel-5.8

I'm making an Online Store with Laravel 5.8 and in this project, I have set *free delivery* for some of the products.

And there are also two types of free delivery: **City Free Delivery** & **Country Free Delivery**.

And also I need to define that, if a user selects multiple products with different delivery types (for example one product has "city free delivery" while the other one has "country free delivery"),  then a message must be shown saying that:

"This product has free delivery but it conflicts the service area with other products that you have chosen."

So the `carts.blade.php` page SHOULD BE looked like this: (expected result)

[image]

But NOW it looks like this:

[image]

But this is wrong because this will check if a single product has `city_free_delivery` and also `country_free_delivery`. So it returns nothing.

So my question is, how can I check that if `prd_delivery` of the products inserted to Cart, has a different delivery area service or not?

And this is also `index` method of `CartsController.php`:

```
public function index()
    {
        $cart = $this->getOpenCartOrCreate();

        // Get the all of send types and set the first send type as default for this cart
        $submit_type = ProductSubmit::query()->get();

        if(!empty($submit_type)) {
            Cart::whereCrt_id($cart->crt_id)->where('crt_completed', 0)->where('crt_send_type', 0)->update(['crt_send_type' => $submit_type[0]->id]);
        }

        $cart = $this->getOpenCartOrCreate();

        $foundOrder = Cart::select('crt_content')->whereCrtId($cart->crt_id)->latest()->first();
        $foundOrder = json_decode($foundOrder->crt_content);

        if ($foundOrder != null) {
            foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
                $prds[] = [
                    Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first(),
                    $value->quantity,
                    $value->price
                ];
            }
        } else {
            $prds = [];
        }
        $cartPrice = json_decode($this->computeAndUpdateCartPrice())->cartPrice;
        $cartDiscountedPrice = json_decode($this->computeAndUpdateCartPrice())->cartDiscountedPrice;
        $sendPrice = $this->computeSendPackagePrice($cart->crt_send_type);

        if (auth()->check()) {
            $user = auth()->user()->usr_id;

            $discounts = CouponUserUses::where('cart_id', $cart->crt_id)->where('user_id', $user)->get();
            foreach ($discounts as $key => $discount) {
                $discountedPrice = 0;

                if ($discount->coupon_end_date < time()) {
                    $user_id = auth()->user()->usr_id;
                    $user_uses = CouponUserUses::where('id', $discount->id)->first();
                    $coupon_id = $user_uses->coupon_id;
                    $cart = $this->getOpenCartOrCreate();
                    $foundOrder = Cart::select('crt_content')->whereCrtId($cart->crt_id)->where('crt_completed', 0)->first();
                    $foundOrder = json_decode($foundOrder->crt_content);
                    $discountedTotal = 0;
                    if ($foundOrder != null) {
                        foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
                            if ($value->coupon == $coupon_id) {
                                $foundOrder[ $key ]->discounted = $value->price;
                                $foundOrder[ $key ]->coupon = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        Cart::whereCrt_id($cart->crt_id)->where('crt_completed', 0)->update(['crt_content' => json_encode($foundOrder)]);
                    }
                    $user_uses->delete();

                }else {
                    foreach ($foundOrder as $index => $value) {
                        if ($discount->coupon_id == $value->coupon) {
                            $discountedPrice += ($value->price - $value->discounted) * $value->quantity;
                        }
                    }
                    $discount['discountedPrice'] = $discountedPrice;
                }
            }
            $membershipDiscount = [
                'type' => MembershipPlan::userTypePersian(),
                'discounted' => MembershipPlan::calculateProductPrice($cartPrice)
            ];
        } else {
            $discounts = [];
            $membershipDiscount = [];
        }

        return view('frontend.shop.carts.index', compact('prds', 'cartPrice', 'cartDiscountedPrice', 'cart', 'submit_type', 'sendPrice', 'discounts', 'membershipDiscount'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a message on all conflicting products. So I've made some change base on your code to do that:

```
$conflicting = false;
$free_delivery = '';

if ($foundOrder != null) {
  foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
    $product = Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first();

    // Just put a check here in case you have some non-free delivery types
    if ($product->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $product->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery') {

      // Check if cart already have free delivery item and it conflict with current looping product or not
      if ($free_delivery && $free_delivery != $product->prd_delivery) {
        $conflicting = true;
      }

      $free_delivery = $product->prd_delivery;
    }

    $prds[] = [
       $product,
       $value->quantity,
       $value->price
    ];
  }
} else {
    $prds = [];
}
...
return view('frontend.shop.carts.index', compact('conflicting', ...));
```

Then in the view (I don't know how you render these products so the below code is just for example):

```
@foreach($prds as $prd)
    @if($conflicting && ($prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'city_free_delivery' || $prd[0]->prd_delivery == 'country_free_delivery'))
        <p style="color:red;">
            This product has free delivery but it conflicts the service area with other products that you have chosen.
        </p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Undefined variable: conflicting

Comment: Did you add it to `compact()`?

Comment: OOPS! I just compacted it and the error is gone. But I don't get the message. I have conflicted products also.

Comment: oh. I've some typos. Can you check it again?

Comment: Again the message `This product has free delivery but it conflicts the service area with other products that you have chosen.` does not appear

Comment: `{{ dd($conflicting) }}` returns false

Comment: Can you print `prd_delivery` attribute of each product? Does it exacly equal `city_free_delivery` or `country_free_delivery`?

Comment: so why the message didn't appear bro?

Comment: Different values were added

Comment: But I don't get the use of `if ($free_delivery && $free_delivery != $product->prd_delivery) {` . Couldn't be `if ($free_delivery != $product->prd_delivery) {` ?

Comment: No. `$free_delivery` is empty at first so if `$product->prd_delivery` has some value then `$free_delivery != $product->prd_delivery` will be true.

Comment: Yes. What's your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234615/discussion-between-tejoslaeslio-and-cuong-le-ngoc).

Comment: Please check my answer.